# Can you disable the mail function in contact form 7

Tags: forms, plugin-contact-form-7, contact

Anyone know if it's possible to disable the mail function in contact form 7?

I know how ludicrous that sounds since that's kind of the point of the plugin, but we make use of the successful mail hook to send to CRM platforms, which have the mail templates handled much better than the standard cf7 emails - effectively sending redundant notifications.

Without just putting in a bogus to email in cf7, is there a way to override the mail send to just return true so our hooks will still work?

The plugin has excellent styling and validation functionality built in so use of the plugin is still perfectly justified. It's not a deal breaker if there's no way to do this. Just would be nice to not have to hack it or set up an email graveyard to send to.

Comment: Questions regarding 3rd party plugins, such as Contact Form 7, is considered to be Off Topic here. That being said, check out this [answer on Stack Overflow!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29927336/800452)